# SQL Group By Problem

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has 3 cols namely points, project_id and creation_date. every time points are assigned a new record has been made, for example.

```
points = 20 project_id = 441 creation_date = 04/02/2011 -> Is one record
points = 10 project_id = 600 creation_date = 04/02/2011 -> Is another record
points = 5 project_id = 441 creation_dae = 06/02/2011 -> Is final record
```

(creation_date is the date on which record is entered and it is achieved by setting the default value to GETDATE())

now the problem is I want to get MAX points grouped by project_id but I also want creation_date to appear with it so I can use it for another purpose, if creation date is repeating its ok and I cannot group by creation_date because if I do so it will skip the points of project with id 600 and its wrong because id 600 is a different project and its only max points are 10 so it should be listed and its only possible if I do the grouping using project_id but then how should I also list creation_date

So far I am using this query to get MAX points of each project

SELECT     MAX(points) AS points, project_id 
FROM         LogiCpsLogs AS LCL 
WHERE     (writer_id = @writer_id) AND (DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()) = DATENAME(mm, creation_date))  AND (points <> 0) 
GROUP BY project_id

writer_id is the ID of writer whose points I want to see, like writer_id = 1, 2 or 3.

This query brings the result of current month only but I would like to list creation_date as well. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery way

```
SELECT P.Project_ID, P.Creation_Date, T.Max_Points
FROM Projects P INNER JOIN
   (
   SELECT Project_ID, MAX(Points) AS Max_Points
   FROM Projects
   GROUP BY Project_ID
   ) T 
ON P.Project_ID = T.Project_ID
AND P.Points = T.Max_Points
```

Please see comment: this will give you ALL days where max-points was achieved. If you only just want one, the query will be more complex.

Edits:

- Misread requirements. Added additional constraint.

Comment: You will also need to JOIN on Points... otherwise you are going to get more records than the question requires.. (only want the creation_date of the item for each project with the max points).   You also need to becareful about the case where equal (max) points have been achieved on different days...  a decision would have to be made to work out if you want all creation_dates where that value of points was achieved, or if you want only the first or last date for example

Comment: AH I misread the requirements. I thought Creation Date was the date the project was created, not the date of the record. Haha! Thanks for proofreading.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you sample..

```
SELECT MAX(POINTS),
       PROJECT_ID,
       CREATION_DATE 
  FROM yourtable
 GROUP by CREATION_DATE,PROJECT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, you don't even need a group by or aggravate functions:

```
SELECT points, project_id, created_date
FROM @T AS LCL
WHERE writer_id = @writer_id AND points <> 0 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 
        FROM @T AS T2 
        WHERE T2.writer_id = @writer_id 
            AND T2.project_id = LCL.project_id 
            AND T2.points > LCL.points)
```

Where `@T` is your table, also if you want to only show the records where they were the total in general and not the total for just this given `@writer_id` then remove the restriction `T2.writer_id = @writer_id` from the inner query

And my code that I used to test:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
writer_id int,
points int,
project_id int,
created_date datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, 20, 441, CAST('20110204' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, 10, 600, CAST('20110204' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, 5, 441, CAST('20110202' AS DATETIME))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, 15, 241, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, 12, 241, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2, 12, 241, GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM @T

DECLARE @writer_id int = 1
```

My results:

```
Result Set (3 items)  
points | project_id | created_date 
20     | 441        | 04/02/2011 00:00:00
10     | 600        | 04/02/2011 00:00:00
15     | 241        | 21/09/2011 18:59:31
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution use CROSS APPLY sub-queries.

For optimal performance I have created an index on project_id (`ASC`) & points (`DESC` sorting order) fields.

If you want to see all `creation_date` values that have maximum points then you can use `WITH TIES`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Project
(
    project_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProjectActivity
(
    project_activity INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,project_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Project(project_id)
    ,points INT NOT NULL
    ,creation_date DATE NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX IX_ProjectActivity_project_id_points_creation_date
ON dbo.ProjectActivity(project_id ASC, points DESC)
INCLUDE (creation_date);
GO

INSERT  dbo.Project
VALUES  (1, 'A'), (2, 'BB'), (3, 'CCC');
INSERT  dbo.ProjectActivity (project_id, points, creation_date)
VALUES  (1,100,'2011-01-01'), (1,110,'2011-02-02'), (1, 111, '2011-03-03'), (1, 111, '2011-04-04')
        ,(2, 20, '2011-02-02'), (2, 22, '2011-03-03')
        ,(3, 2, '2011-03-03');

SELECT  p.*, ca.*
FROM    dbo.Project p
CROSS APPLY
(
        SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES
                pa.points, pa.creation_date 
        FROM    dbo.ProjectActivity pa
        WHERE   pa.project_id = p.project_id 
        ORDER BY pa.points DESC
) ca;

DROP TABLE dbo.ProjectActivity;
DROP TABLE dbo.Project;
```